Is a cube an orientable surface?
In Calculus (James Stewart), we learn that a surface $S$ is orientable if, for each point $x \in S$, we can choose an unity normal vector $N(x)$ in such a way that the vector field $N$ varies smoothly on $S$.
We see, as a example, that the Möbius strip is not orientable because the normal vector field "jumps".
On the other hand, some exercises ask to find the flux of a vector field through a cube, considering the outward orientation. I understand what the exercise meant, but...
How is it possible to define a smooth unity normal field on the surface of a cube? What about the edges and corners? I can't wrap my mind around it. Can anyone, please, help?

Well, I don't understand what the exercise says. The surface of a cube is not a manifold, not with inherited differential structure anyway. It is homeomorphic to a sphere, and thus we can transfer sphere's structure onto it, but then it is no longer a cube, is it?

The idea of the exercise is to calculate the flux of the vector field trough the faces of the cube, considering an outward unity normal vector field defined on each of its faces. So we can sum four integrals to get that.

What I think is weird is that the flux is defined for orientable surfaces, as the definition above. But, is the cube orientable in this sense (smooth normal vector field)?

It's the union of 6 orientables in the same way you have piecewise smooth (but not smooth) paths.

But, isn't orientation a global feature? When one say that a surface is orientable doesn't it mean that we can define a smooth unity normal field on the whole surface? Is it ok to say that a cube is an orientable surface? Or... the cube is not orientable, but you can calculate a flux through a cube because it is "piecewise orientable"!? The edges has null measure. Maybe that is the reason. How did I go?!

It's a global feature of a smooth manifold, in the same way differentiability is a feature of a smooth path.  I think your way of thinking about it is correct.  (roughly "piecewise orientable")

Thank you for the clarifying discussion.

It would be better to talk about a continuous (and, additionally, piecewise-smooth) normal vector field.
